# Trying to understand why the largest singular value of $M_n^{-1}$ is $1.4286$ no matter what $n$ I choose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, singular-values

Let $n \ge 3$ be an odd number. Let $I_n$ be the $n$ dimensional identity matrix and let $A_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix where every element is zero except the central element which is, say, $0.3$. For example, for $n=3$ and $n=5$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
I_3
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \\
A_3
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \\
I_5
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \\
A_5
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
$$
Then define the block matrix $M_n$ by
$$
\begin{align}
M_n
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
I_n & A_n & A_n \\
A_n & I_n & A_n \\
A_n & A_n & I_n
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
$$
No matter what value of $n$ I choose I find that the largest singular value of $M_n^{-1}$ is $1.4286$. How can this be explained?

Here is some Matlab code that demonstrates this phenomenon.

```
I_3 = [1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,1];
A_3 = [0,0,0;0,0.3,0;0,0,0];
M_3 = [I_3, A_3, A_3; A_3, I_3, A_3; A_3, A_3, I_3];
M_3_inv = inv(M_3);

I_5 = [1,0,0,0,0;0,1,0,0,0;0,0,1,0,0;0,0,0,1,0;0,0,0,0,1];
A_5 = [0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0.3,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;];
M_5 = [I_5, A_5, A_5; A_5, I_5, A_5; A_5, A_5, I_5];
M_5_inv = inv(M_5);

I_7 = [...
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0;...
    0,1,0,0,0,0,0;...
    0,0,1,0,0,0,0;...
    0,0,0,1,0,0,0;...
    0,0,0,0,1,0,0;...
    0,0,0,0,0,1,0;...
    0,0,0,0,0,0,1];
A_7 = [...
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0;...
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0;...
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0;...
    0,0,0,0.3,0,0,0;...
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0;...
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0;...
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
M_7 = [I_7, A_7, A_7; A_7, I_7, A_7; A_7, A_7, I_7];
M_7_inv = inv(M_7);

[U_3,S_3,V_3] = svd(M_3_inv);
[U_5,S_5,V_5] = svd(M_5_inv);
[U_7,S_7,V_7] = svd(M_7_inv);

max(diag(S_3))
max(diag(S_5))
max(diag(S_7))
```

Comment: In $I_3$ I assume the bottom right cell is a typo?

Comment: Also if you want speed up input I believe you can use the input I_5=eye(5); etc, as the eye(n) function returns an identity matrix of dimensions $n\times n$. Additionally for A you can use commands like A_5=zeros(5); followed by A(3,3)=0.3;

Comment: $1.4268$ is (approx) the inverse of $1-0.3$, and the ev of $M_n$ are 1's, $1-0.3$ twice and whatever the other one is.

Comment: Just reorder your basis: on most of the elements $M$ acts as the identity, and then there's a little $3\times 3$ block which is $1$ on diagonal and $0.3$ elsewhere - such matrices' eigenvalues are well known.

Comment: @HenryLee I switched to R for the last year so my Matlab is a bit rusty :)

Comment: ahh I see, was just trying to save you some time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that $M_n$ is symmetric, which means that $M_n^{-1}$ is symmetric, which means that its maximal singular value is equal to its spectral radius (the maximal absolute value among its eigenvalues).

Let $\otimes$ denote the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). We can write your matrix as
$$
M_n = J \otimes A_n + I_{3n},
$$
where $J$ is the $3 \times 3$ matrix
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0}.
$$
Verify that the eigenvalues of $J$ are $-1,-1,2$. On the other hand, $A_n$ has eigenvalue $0.3$ with multiplicity $1$ and $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$. Correspondingly, the properties of the Kronecker product allow us to find that $J \otimes A_n$ has eigenvalues $2 \times 0.3 = 0.6$ with multiplicity $1$, $-0.3$ with multiplicity $2$, and $0$ with multiplicity $3(n-1)$.

Let $P_n = J \otimes A_n$ so that $M_n^{-1} = (I_{3n} + P_n)^{-1}$. The eigenvalues of $(I_{3n} + P_n)^{-1}$ are equal to $(1 + \lambda)^{-1}$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $P_n$. With that, we see that the eigenvalues of $M_n^{-1}$ are equal to
$$
1/(1 + 0.6), \quad 1/(1 - 0.3), \quad 1/(1 - 0).
$$
Among these, the largest absolute value is $|1/(0-0.3)| = 1.4286$. So, this is the maximal singular value of $M_n.$

---

In addition to facilitating our analysis, the Kronecker product also gives us a nice way to express this matrix in Matlab:

```
A_7 = zeros(7)
A_7(4,4) = 0.3
J = ~eye(3)
M = kron(J,A_7) + eye(3*7)
```

Comment: Thanks, its nice to see such a comprehensive explanation. I think it should be $I_{3n}$ in the last paragraph instead of $I$ as the identity matrix I'm considering is also growing in size with increasing $n$.